# save lost data by ddrescue

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I have lost datas in a memory card. So, I decided to use ddrescue. Fine. But after running command

`sudo ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sda5 logfile`, I lost all my data in `/dev/sda5`. I don't know why.

And I found that

> Destination will be overwritten ─ so make sure destination is free of important data.

How can I recover my data in `/dev/sda5`? Should I continue to using `ddrescue`?

Comment: This is spiraling out of control. I would stop until you understand the command better.

Comment: You explicitly told ddrescue to format the sda5 drive with a copy of the sdb1 drive. Peculiar choice given that usually one wants to save an image of the drive, not ddrescue it onto another drive. But anyways, you told nothing about the file system that was on sda5.

Comment: Please specify the sizes of `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sda5`, as well as what `/dev/sda5` was used for.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to safely make the rescue image a regular file, like this:

```
sudo ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb1 memorycard.iso memorycard.log
```