# ddrescue Understand

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

sorry about my English...

I have lost dates on my External  hard disk with **dd** (I have on my External hard disk with **ext4 format** and have only videos and some Files), now to try the dates from my hard disk to recover. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401005) to find how to does it

```
sudo ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb1 memorycard.iso memorycard.log
```

Why **agc** use two possibility , **.iso** and **.log** for save ?

else, a more question....

he give only **/sdb1** not the output hard drive **/sda5**

maybe is well

```
ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sda5/_rescue.img /dev/sda5/rescue.log
```

Can Please someone explain with easy words because he does it, Thanks!

Comment: The info page, `info ddrescue` is a very good document including a tutorial with relevant examples including the command lines that you show in the question. Please read slowly twice. That is what i did in order to learn how to use it. And `ddrescue` has been a very useful tool for me. -- Please notice that you should use `ddrescue` with `root` privileges, so be careful and double check the target device. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `man` pages for `ddrescue` are [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html).

The command options tell `ddrescue` to

```
-f
```

Force overwrite of block devices if you are **not** copying your data to a regular file. In this case the option will do nothing because you **are** making a copy to a regular `img` file.

```
-r3
```

Retry any bad sectors 3 times

```
/dev/sdb1
```

The path to the damaged drive you are trying to rescue. It should be connected but **not** mounted. Plug the drive in and run `lsblk` to see the correct path.

```
/path/to/rescue.img
```

Is just where you want to copy the rescued data to and can be any mounted drive with enough space for the copy. Don't use `/dev/` paths, just normal ones into your regular file system like `/home/user/whatever`

```
/path/to/rescue.log
```

Is where `ddrescue` will record it's progress so that if you stop it then it can resume from where it stopped and not have to start again. Again use normal path descriptions.

If the damaged drive is at `/dev/sdb1` then just open a terminal **in the location you want to copy the data to** and run

```
 sudo ddrescue -r3 /dev/sdb1 rescue.img rescue.log
```

**EDIT**

Once you have recovered your image then you will need to `mount` it. There is some help [here](https://fossbytes.com/mounting-isos-image-file-types-in-linux/) but if you have an `img` file then you may find it easier to install `losetup` to help with the `mount`. You could also try specifying an `iso` format instead of an `img` and see if your file manager can open this directly (since @acg originally suggested the `iso`).

Once mounted you can also use `testdisk` to examine the iso for any deleted and lost files.

Comment: Very Thanks for your guidance!, one more Question, and when have my copy rescue.img on hard disk /sdc, what should I do and it to start ?

Comment: very Thanks! i wish you a nice weekend!